# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after add security configuration to my spring project

Tags: spring, spring-security

Configuration File

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity public class WebConfiguration {

// Create Security Chain
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/create-admin").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/index/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/dashboard").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "Manager", "Accountant")
            .requestMatchers("/employees/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "Manager", "HumanResourceManager")
            .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin", "Manager")

            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .failureForwardUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",true)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")

            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")

            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");


    return http.build();
   }
}
```

Login Mapping

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView loginUI(){
    ModelAndView loginUI = new ModelAndView();
    loginUI.setViewName("login.html");
    return loginUI;
}
```

When I trying to view the UI using http://localhost:8080/login I got error like this. I have tried clearing the cookies and cache also but still getting the same error.

[ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJBUw.png)

But, when I change my mapping like this to return a string it works fine.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
public String loginUI(){
    return "loginUI";
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that in second method you are using return "loginUI" that means your view page is loginUI.html but in first case when you are stting the url you are using

```
  loginUI.setViewName("login.html");
```

Change first case like following it will work

```
 loginUI.setViewName("loginUI.html");
```

Comment: No, actually my UI name is "login.html" I just return a string in second case to let you know that only UIs are not returning. It doesn't return the UI.

Comment: can you show me your login.html page

Comment: @GetMapping(value = "/login")
public String loginUI(){
    return "login";
}                                                                                                                                                             You can directly use this to redirect to your login page

Comment: <form action="/login" method="POST" role="form text-left">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="txtUsername" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="txtPassword" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </form>

Comment: This is what I have in my login.html body

Comment: as i can see that in action you are again redirecting to same url /login thats why you are getting error you need to change that action url first and beacause it will form a loop beacuse your controller and form action both are redirecting towards each other

Comment: Use some other url in form action and make another handler method in your controller to collect the form data

Comment: Still getting the same issue. :(

Comment: show me your full code all code of controller as well as all view code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CYJLb6U0zBYSdoiLRoR-mwuFrsPQluYZ?usp=share_link

Comment: Please use the above link to view the full codes.

Comment: okay for 10 mins

Comment: can you tell me about error wheter error is still same

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJBUw.png

Comment: This page isn't working at the momentlocalhost redirected you too many times.
To fix this issue, try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS